# Why we need a Skew-symmetric matrix to define acceleration?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, acceleration

Peoples ! Thanks you for your time.

I have a question about acceleration equation.

$$\begin{bmatrix}f_{x}\\ f_{y}\\ f_{z}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\dot{u}\\\dot{v}\\ \dot{w}\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}0  & w & -v \\ -w & 0 & u \\ v  & -u & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}p\\ q\\ r\end{bmatrix}+g\begin{bmatrix}\sin\theta \\-\cos\theta \sin\phi\\ -\cos\theta \cos\phi\end{bmatrix}$$

Here, why $uvw$ should be skew-symmetric matrix and 
why skew-symmetric matrix of $uvw$ should be multiplied with $pqr$?

Please, let me know.

Comment: So what does the different terms denote? I assume what is going on is related to a rotating rigid body with torques, but it is not obvious. Without that information the question is pretty unclear.

Comment: What is the context of this equation? It looks like spatial acceleration from fluids to me.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely related to motion in a rotating frame.  The antisymmetric matrix follows because this term is of the form $R^{-1}dR$, where $R$ is a rotation matrix.  In particular $R$ is orthogonal so $R^{-1}=R^T$ and $R^TR=\hat{1}$.

Take the differential of this:
$$
0=(dR^T)R+R^TdR=(R^TdR)^T+ R^TdR
$$
showing that $\Omega=R^TdR$ plus its transpose is nil, i.e. $\Omega^T+\Omega=0$, meaning $\Omega$ is antisymmetric.

This term is the rate of change of a rotating frame as seen from a lab frame.

So why should we need to consider $R^TdR$?  Take any *fixed* rotation matrix $R_0$ and consider $R_0R=r$.  The matrix $r$ is simply the compound rotation of $R_0$ and the original $R$, i.e. we have done a rotational shift of $R_0$ to the coordinate system.  Note then that $r^T dr= R^TR_0^T R_0 dR$ since $R_0$ is constant.  Since $R_0$ is a rotation, $R_0^TR=\hat 1$ so that $r^T dr= R^TdR$, independent of $R_0$, and thus independent of the shift of origin in the rotational coordinates.

It’s not clear what the other pieces are since you have not defined your variables explicitly.

Comment: Thanks you for your time, Mr, ZeroTheHero. 

The variables $uvw$ and $pqr$ in that term denotes Linear Velocity and Angular Velocity.

Answer (score 1):

If rotational velocity is $$\vec{\omega} = \pmatrix{p \\ q \\ r}$$

and linear velocity is $$ \vec{v} = \pmatrix{u \\ v \\ w} $$ then the equation is

$$ \vec{f} = \dot{\vec{v}} + \vec{v} \times \vec{\omega} + \vec{g} $$

The skew-symmetric matrix is the [cross product operator matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Conversion_to_matrix_multiplication) defined as follows

$$ \pmatrix{ x \\ y \\z} \times = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -z & y \\ z & 0 & -x \\ -y & x & 0 \end{bmatrix} $$

As for the meaning for the equation, not enough information is provided by the *op*.

From my own experience the term $$\vec{a} = \dot{\vec{v}} - \vec{\omega} \times \vec{v} = \dot{\vec{v}} + \vec{v} \times \vec{\omega}$$ is the [spatial acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_acceleration) of a particle, whilst $\dot{\vec{v}}$ is the material acceleration. Spatrial acceleration relates to how a velocity field changes under a fixed reference point, while material acceleration relates how the velocity of a moving particle changes.

Comment: **edit** I had flipped the vectors for linear and rotational velocity in my mind. I fixed this in my answer now.